# Why are tombstones needed in an open addressing hashtable?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, hashtable

For removal, I would just keep searching until reaching the last occupied cell, then I will swap it with the value I want to delete if I encountered it earlier and clear the last cell. I'm not sure why tombstones are needed at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the same bucket can be part of the post-collision search chain for any number of hashed-to buckets.  When you "clear the last cell" (bucket), all collision search chains that pass through that bucket will then see the cleared bucket and if they follow the usual hash-table logic they'll stop searching (and if they were part of another collision chain than yours, not notice other same-hashed-to-bucket content), and if they don't (follow the usual logic i.e.) stop searching there then all lookups will be less efficient as they use some weird logic to determine when to stop.

The simplest case - linear probing: you can find a cluster of elements and move them to the right places so future lookups work - it's just more proactive work that might or might not be useful later.  Sometimes lazy is good (e.g. you might grow the table to the point where you rehash before the tombstones become problematically numerous).  It's ***much*** harder - generally impractical - to compact if using more complicated search chains, even something fairly simple like quadratic probing.

To elaborate on the linear probing case, consider:

```
bucket#      bucket#-bucket's-key-hashed-to
...
 9           <clear>
10           10
11           10
12           11
13           10
14           14
15           11
16           10
17           11
18           10
19           19
20           <clear>
...
```

As illustrated, the cluster of ten values in buckets [10..19] have keys that hashed to buckets 10, 11, 14 or 19.

Say we want to delete the entry stored in bucket [15].  Hashing the key for it will take us to bucket [11], then we'll search linearly until we reach [15] and find a match.  If we want to compact instead of suing tombstones, we must continue searching from bucket [15] to [20] before we can know we've found the last key that hashes to [11] (namely, at [17]).  Then how do we delete?

Your idea was to move bucket [17] content to [15], clearing [17], but afterwards linear probing for the key in bucket [18] would search from [10..17] - see it's clear - and stop without inspecting bucket 18.  Similarly, insertion of that same key would place a duplicate at 17.

It is possible to compact things correctly to maintain the normal invariants for linear probing, but it's fiddly.  The "rules" are:

- we can't move something before the bucket it hashes to (so [19] can't be "compacted" into an earlier bucket)
- if we  a bucket, all values in the rest of the cluster (here [10..19] that hash to a bucket above the bucket we clear must be stored above the bucket we clear

In this case, we could "move" [18] to [15], leaving [18] .

Now, if you think about how all that worked, a lot of the analysis was possible because we knew all relevant data was clustered between cleared buckets, in buckets [10..19].  Collision handling that's more elaborate - like quadratic probing - means the members of the collision chains around the bucket you're trying to delete from can be anywhere else in the table.  The  elements no longer demarcate clusters of elements that all hashed within a quickly discernable range of buckets close to where you're hashing to for your deletion operation.

Summarily, this kind of compaction technique isn't easy or fast for the simplest linear probing collision-handling option, and is impractical for most other collision-handling.

Comment: Thanks, I wrongly assumed that each cell in the chain belongs to one and only chain.

Comment: Maybe it's still possible if you save the chain starting point together with the data upon insertion. And then you clear the last cell that belongs to the same chain of the value you are trying to delete.

Comment: @RonenFestinger: I can't see how that can work.  Firstly, "save the chain starting point together with the data upon insertion" doesn't enable any different logic, as the chain starting point can be recovered by re-hash the key (and folding into the bucket count) anyway.  Secondly, "clear the last cell that belongs to the same chain of the value you are trying to delete" - that's the same scenario we'd already discussed, isn't it?

Comment: I mean if keep record of  the chain each value belongs to, we can compact the chain when removing an element in the middle of it. We can do it by marking each value in the chain with its starting cell, there can't be a same value that belong to two different chains, right? So when we remove a value from the middle of a chain and replace it with another value of the same chain, we don't break the insertion and search algorithm. Same value will always belong to one chain, the position of it in the chain depends on the order of insertion of other values in the chain.

Comment: @RonenFestinger "So when we remove a value from the middle of a chain and replace it with another value of the same chain, we don't break the insertion and search algorithm." - yes you do: not for that chain you're removing from, but for any other chain(s) that pass through the bucket you clear out to replace it with.  For example, if we try to remove something that hashes to bucket [10] but ended up due to collisions at bucket [19] by replacing it with a value from bucket [35] (that also hashed to [10]), then if there's another chain that passes through [35] it will see a cleared element.

Comment: Thanks, I see the problem now. The last cell which we removed could have been passed by another chain and now we have a hole there so this other chain won't be able to go over it when searching for a value after that hole.